# Spring - mongoDb Error: com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: "invalid ns to index"

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 4 application that is using 2 datasources, one being MongoDB. When I do a near query I get the following error:

*org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "aValideMongoDB" , "err" : "invalid ns to index" , "code" : 10096 , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 955 , "ok" : 1.0}*

The code that is failing:

```
private List<GeoSearchDealer> doDealerQuery(NearQuery nearQuery, DistanceKind distanceKind) {
    // FAILS AT THIS LINE
    GeoResults<InventoryDealer> results = mongoTemplate.geoNear(nearQuery, InventoryDealer.class);
    List<GeoSearchDealer> dealers = new ArrayList<GeoSearchDealer>();

    for (GeoResult<InventoryDealer> result : results) {
        ...
    }

    return dealers;
}
```

Everything is created programatically, so no XML. Here is the config class:

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan("path.to.code.base") 
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMongoRepositories("path.to.code.base")
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class AppConfig {

    // other beans omitted for brevity

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoHost);
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, mongoDb);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

The InventoryDealer class:

```
@Document(collection="inventory_dealer")
public class InventoryDealer {
    ...
}
```

pom.xml:

```
    <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

This code was ported from a prototype application that was working, but was using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

So some of the Geo* classes has to have some imports changed, but nothing major, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I will answer my own question after the day or so wait period, but in essence, there is a bug in version 2.11.3 of the java mongo driver and if you use the latest version, you can only use 1.4.1 or earlier of the spring-data-mongodb library.

Comment: I Have a suggestion for something to look into, I use mongo but not with Spring, so take this with a grain of salt - I only mention it since you mention changes to something you're doing with geo  and an error that mentions  indexing - mongo has had some changes in allowable geo indexes - it's possible to have indexes that might give you write errors - e.g. writing an invalid GeoJson object to a 2dsphere index. Check to see if you can do the same write you're trying to do directly in the shell - if it's an illegal write the shell will display the same error.

Comment: @SteveB The issue is as stated - there's a driver issue. I knew the query worked when I ported it as the prototype worked, but used older versions of the libraries. I ported everything to the newest version and it all stopped working. I went to an older version and it started working. It's the combination of the java-mongo-driver 2.11.3 and spring-data-mongodb 1.6.1 that blows up. Move either version back and it starts to work. I chose to go back to java-mongo-driver 2.11.0

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the Spring Driver If I use this pom.xml configuration, it works with the latest mongo:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>2.11.3</version> -->
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    <!-- <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version> -->
</dependency>
```

But if I use version 2.11.3, it fails with the error listed below.

Driver 2.11.3 works with 1.2.0 - 1.4.1, but starts to fail with 1.5.1